# In How To Ask page what does it exactly mean by "Begin by improving your existing questions"?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

I previously asked a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367599/why-i-am-banned-from-asking-questions-even-after-doing-some-positive-contributio) regarding Question ban. After the suggestion of many users and reading the How To Ask page as per my understanding I fixed the posts by editing and tried to make them on topic. Also, the page says

> "The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh the cost of those questions which were poorly received."

Q1)Now what does this statement mean, you all can visit my [Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6947385/lucifer) and help me if my contributions are worthy to lift question ban or not?

Q2)What is exact meaning of fix existing posts? should I edit and ask a whole new question, if no then what's the point of editing the post for which I have already received the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1) It means that if your new questions are upvoted and you asked enough (how much is kept secret, I've no clue) to counter balance the downvoted questions, then the ban is removed.

Q2) Try to get those question in a good shape, fix writing, give context, make them reproducible, so people seeing them now will be more interested in upvoting them than downvoting them.

Comment: what you explained for Q1) I was banned once previously I waited for ~6~ months to as a question I did ask the question In proper flow like what I am facing , what I tried and asked for help.Then i found sol. answered my own question after no one gave response to it. I posted meta post about My ban again people who visited that question gave a serious amount of criticism on it(which I have gotten over)

Comment: Q2) AS mentioned in the how to ask blog I tried and improved my existing question btw for which I already had the sol. thats why I said asked this question on meta, the edits which I made on the existing posts, how are they going to help me if the question is already answered.

Comment: @Lucifer think about how this question may help others (that's the goal and why we vote on questions, would they be useful for other in the future) with the same problem, try to find how to make it easy to find and easy to understand

Comment: you have answered in the most generic way possible , can you  be more specific , how can I improve?